# Removing "#" comments with JQ

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

In the [FAQ for jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json), it says:

> As noted in the previous Q, jq itself can be used to transform nearly-valid JSON to JSON in many instances. **For example, "#" comments can be removed using jq.**

However, I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to actually do this with jq. What's the proper way to read a JSON file that has "#" comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Summary

Following your link to the jq FAQ, we find the exact quote:

> [...] Thus you may be able to use `jq -n -f FILENAME` to convert nearly-valid JSON to JSON.

*That's exactly the case here.*

---

#### Explanation

A file that's almost JSON, but has `#` comments, *is going to be valid `jq` code*. Thus, if you have an input file created by the shell command:

```
cat >input.notjson <<'EOF'
{
  "This is a key": "This is a value" # this is a comment, which is why this is not JSON
}
EOF
```

...you can run it as a jq program:

```
jq -nf input.notjson
```

...to get as output:

```
{
  "This is a key": "This is a value"
}
```

...which can thereafter be fed as input to another, arbitrary jq program (or other consumer of JSON).

Comment: FYPI, there's a catch using jq for expunging comments: jq programs cannot be too large.  So the other solutions mentioned in the FAQ (e.g. hjson, any-json) are worth knowing about.